# Jquery - Animate up then change z-index then animate down

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

I know there is an easier way to achieve what I am doing here with out duplicating the jQuery and targeting each of the three separate divs:

```
    $(function() {
    var $foo = $('.img-spot-wrap-1');
    $foo.hover(function() {
                clearTimeout($foo.t);
                $foo.stop().animate({top: '-40px', height: 210} ,{duration:300}).animate({top: '0px'} ,{duration:300});
            }, function(){
                $foo.t = setTimeout((function() {
                    $foo.stop().animate({top: '-40px'} ,{duration:300}).animate({top: '0px', height: 170} ,{duration:300});
                }), 200);
        });
});

$(function() {
    var $foo = $('.img-spot-wrap-2');
    $foo.hover(function() {
                clearTimeout($foo.t);
                $foo.stop().animate({top: '-40px', height: 210} ,{duration:300}).animate({top: '0px'} ,{duration:300});
            }, function(){
                $foo.t = setTimeout((function() {
                    $foo.stop().animate({top: '-40px'} ,{duration:300}).animate({top: '0px', height: 170} ,{duration:300});
                }), 200);
        });
});

$(function() {
    var $foo = $('.img-spot-wrap-3');
    $foo.hover(function() {
                clearTimeout($foo.t);
                $foo.stop().animate({top: '-40px', height: 210} ,{duration:300}).animate({top: '0px'} ,{duration:300});
            }, function(){
                $foo.t = setTimeout((function() {
                    $foo.stop().animate({top: '-40px'} ,{duration:300}).animate({top: '0px', height: 170} ,{duration:300});
                }), 200);
        });
});
```

each div could have the same class name but when they do they all perform this action on hover instead of the specific div that is hovered on. I'm basically wondering how I can have only the hovered div perform the action and the remaining divs with the same class do nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: YOu need to look into `$(this)`.  It will help you create a function for a single class that only works on the class you are working on.  I will try submitting some code

Answer (score 0):

Your question title asks about changing z-index while animating.  But your description asks nothing about it.  What would you like to do?

Here's some code to consolidate.

```
$('.oneClassName').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $(this).stop().animate({top: '-40px', height: 210}, 300).animate({top: '0px'}, 300);
}, function() {
    var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({top: '-40px'}, 300).animate({top: '0px', height: 170}, 300);
    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: After reading the title again I can see how it really has nothing to do with my question. My apologizes but thank you, "this" was the missing link!

Answer (score 0):

Please use $(this) for the element that you actually hovered:

```
$(function() {
    var $foo = $('.img-spot-wrap-3');
    $foo.hover(function() {
                clearTimeout($(this).t);
                $(this).stop().animate({top: '-40px', height: 210} ,{duration:300}).animate({top: '0px'} ,{duration:300});
            }, function(){
                $(this).t = setTimeout((function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({top: '-40px'} ,{duration:300}).animate({top: '0px', height: 170} ,{duration:300});
                }), 200);
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PfLaG/1/